# Initialising custom resources in MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, resx

I am creating my own resource files via T4, since they are saved in the database.

The result is for example:

```
namespace Resources
{
    public class Backoffice {

        internal static IResourceProvider resourceProvider = 
             new JsonResourceProvider(
                 "Backoffice", 
                 (int)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["ApplicationId"]);

        public static string AlgemeenActief 
        {
             get {
                 var resource = 
                     resourceProvider.GetResource(
                         "AlgemeenActief",
                         CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name);

                 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(resource))
                 {
                     switch ($"{CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name}_{(int) System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["ApplicationId"]}")
                     {
                         default:
                         case "nl-NL_6":
                             return "Actief";
                         case "en-GB_6":
                             return "Active";
                     }
                 }
                 return resource;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This allows me to use my resources in the same way as the standard .NET resources (I can now type `Resources.Backoffice.AlgemeenActief`, and I have intellisense showing me the properties).

I get an error because the class is not initialised however. Im not sure how they are initialised in .NET however. I tried to find usages of the constructor in a microsoft resource class:

```
internal Backoffice() {
}
```

This does not return any results. Does anyone know how the resource objects are initiated and how I can mimic this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you could make your class static:

```
public static class Backoffice
```

and call the property getter like this:

```
var resource = Backoffice.AlgemeenActief;
```

Alternatively, leave your class definition as it is and instantiate a BackOffice object like this:

```
var backOffice = new BackOffice();
```

and call the property getter like this:

```
var resource = backOffice.AlgemeenActief;
```

Comment: @Kai Did this answer your question?

Comment: it got it working, yeah, so thanks! But now I am still intrigued to know how Microsoft handles it and why they do not use static classes for their resource files :D